# I want to disable cod when 100 cod orders is completed in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I want to disable the cod  delivery feature in the order page of prestashop 1.6.3 when  100 /50 orders (  this will be a parameter)  is completed per day.

How to disable this programmatically by finding out whether 100 cod is been completed .

[image]

Comment: You can't do this from out-of-the-box Prestashop. You'll have to create your own module, and hook on Payment hooks to query the DB and see how many COD payments have been done during a given day.

Comment: "select count(*) AS cod_count from ps_orders where module='cashondelivery' and date(date_add) = CURDATE() and ( current_state= 3 or current_state=4) "  - This  query is rite ?
Please  check  my answer that i posted  I will  modify the hookPayment  in cashondelivery module

Answer (score 1):

I will modify the hookPayment() in cashondelivery module to do this :

```
 public function hookPayment($params)
{

    if (!$this->active)
        return ;

    global $smarty;

    // Check if cart has product download
    if ($this->hasProductDownload($params['cart']))
        return false;
    //Check whether the cod done exceeds the daily limit if yes dont display the cod option
    $cod_limit  = Configuration::get('PS_KITS_COD_DAILY_LIMIT');//  number of cod
    $sql        = "select count(*) AS cod_count from ps_orders where module='cashondelivery' and date(date_add) = CURDATE() and ( current_state= 3 or current_state=4)";    
    if ($row = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql)){
    $cod_count        = $row['cod_count']; 
    }
    if ($cod_count  >= $cod_limit){
    return ;
    }
    $smarty->assign(array(
        'this_path' => $this->_path, //keep for retro compat
        'this_path_cod' => $this->_path,
        'this_path_ssl' => Tools::getShopDomainSsl(true, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->name.'/'
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payment.tpl');
}
```